# How to assign List<Parent> to List<Child> which is parent extended with 2 additional properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making ASP.NET MVC app and i have class `Order` but i want to have 2 additional properties in it just for view. I figured out i will just make a class `ViewOrder` which derives from `Order` and has 2 additional properties so i could just assign `Order` object to `OrderView` and then set those 2 properties and pass this object to view.

Is it the proper way? When i was looking for answer on casting people were giving examples like "Cat inherits from mammal. You can't cast mammal to cat because it could be a dog" or something like that.

**List:**

```
var orderList = new List<Order>(_context.Orders)
```

**Like that it doesn't even compile:**

```
List<OrderView> orderViewList = (List<OrderView>)orderList;
```

**This compile but throws "InvalidCastException":**

```
var orderViewList = orderList.Cast<OrderView>().ToList();
```

Comment: You cannot cast from an object of a base type to a more derived type, that is why you get an InvalidCastException on the last. Since the objects in the source list are orders, but not OrderViews, you cannot cast an order to an OrderView.

Comment: An `OrderView` is *always* an `Order` but an `Order` is not always an `OrderView`. You can do something like `orderList.Select(order => new OrderView() { newprop = '', newprop1 = '', ///rest }).ToList()`

Comment: And `List<BaseType>` is not a base type for `List<DerivedType>`, generics doesn't work like that, that is why the middle code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution is to perform an explicit mapping operation:

```
List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>(_context.Orders);
List<OrderView> orderViewList = new List<OrderView>();  // Empty.

foreach (Order order in orderList)
{
    OrderView orderView = new OrderView;
    orderView.OrderNo = order.OrderNo;
    orderView.CustomerId = order.CustomerId;
    // ... etc
    orderViewList.Add(orderView);
}
```

Comment: yeah, but i wanted to avoid that

Comment: Can you share your code @kkamil4sz, that way we'd be able to suggest the best approach because based on what we know for now, robbpriestkey's answer is the way.

Comment: i mean, i wanted just some faster way than to manually map all parent class properties (Like List = List) but i guess i dont have a choice.

Comment: I wouldn't be too concerned about it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast base class to derived class, there is no built-in method. You can either write a constructor OrderView(Order) that can do the conversion and use Linq to make it look clean.

```
// OrderView constructor
public OrderView(Order order)
{
    this.OrderNo = order.OrderNo;
}

// Linq to create new list
List<OrderView> orderView = orders.Select(o => new OrderView(o));
```

Or use it this way, but not recommended

```
List<Order> orders = new List<OrderView>();
```

Comment: I still need to map everything but yeah, at least i need to do it only once

Answer (score 0):

I must apologize for the previous answer. The problem lies here:

`List<OrderView> orderViewList = (List<OrderView>)orderList; //<== Casting`

The real truth is: `Order` is the parent of `Orderview`. So you cannot create a parent and assign it to a child. You can only create a child and assign it to a parent.

*So, `OrderView` is another version of `Order`. But `Order` is not a version of `OrderView`.*

**Here's a thorough example:**

when a child is assigned to a parent, any other features the parent doesn't have that the child has are ignored. But features that are required by a child,  are required from a parent when that parent is assigned to a child. Which generates this casting issue.

I am not sure if what you're trying to do will serve you in the long run but there's probably a better approach of doing it. Please provide your `Order` class and identify what you specifically want to achieve with `OrderView`. Because the way I understand it, `OrderView` is supposed to be a method within `Order` provides a representation of `Order` you can simply create those extra fields you mentioned as private fields so that you can use them to create this `OrderView()` method.

Comment: I get "cannot imlicitly convert Generic.List<Order> to Generic.List<OrderView>"